# Autoload "amsmath" style hook

Tags: auctex

How do I autoload the "amsmath" style hook with all my `.tex` files?

Currently, it is triggered only when I add `\usepackage{amsmath}` to my `.tex` file; there are other packages and classes that autoload amsmath and Auctex does not seem to recognise that out of the box.

Comment: Which other packages or classes do you have in mind?  Can you please tell the names?

Comment: Dear Arash: Thank you for asking! I don't know how I missed this! I thought there was no interest in the question! The most notable one is smfart, smfbook (smf classes). I wonder if mathtools also `\Require`s it? At any rate, it extends the functionality in `amsmath` and could use similar style hooks as `amsmath`. I'd be happy to collaborate on this if there's interest! Thank you!